# Preposition - "build by" or "build from"

Tags: prepositions

I have a 'statement' and I build a package according to the statement.

Which one is correct (for a function name (programing)) ?

"build package by statement"

"build package from statement"

Comment: *build a package **according to** the statement*

Comment: If you're looking for the name of a function then the requirement is usually that it's **terse**, and intuitive, rather than grammatically correct.  So, you can call your function whatever you want

Comment: @MaxWilliams I don't know if you are into programing, but we have code style guides, specific terms and standards to stick to. Calling a function "whatever you want" is considered bad practice mostly and using wrong wordings can be really annoying.

Comment: I know the term "build from scratch" so it makes more sense to me using "from" than using "by"

Comment: I suppose what I meant was you are not **bound** by the rules, conventions and semantics of the english language, which is the focus of this forum.

Comment: A building can be built *by* a builder *from* blueprints. Is the statement closer to a builder or to blueprints?

Comment: @MaxWilliams ok, this is correct. But I try to stick to correct grammar as much as possible tho. But you are right that's more a personal thing @Peter Shor good advice. I think it's `from` what I need to use then

Comment: @MaxWilliams: I don't agree that word choice and grammar don't apply when naming functions. The name doesn't need to be a complete sentence, but using the wrong word in this instance would be very confusing for other programmers trying to understand OP's code.

Comment: @HerbCaudill I totally agree - I'm a programmer myself.  That's why i said, in my first comment on this post, "the requirement is usually that it's terse, and **intuitive** (my added emphasis) rather than grammatically correct".  By this i didn't mean that grammar was completely uninmportant, just that it wasn't the **most important thing**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second name is correct. You are building the package *from* the information contained in the statement.